Parallax effects for a horizontal carousel?
I'm trying to implement a horizontal scrolling carousel with a parallax effect on the images using Framer Motion's useScroll and useTransform hooks. However, the parallax effect doesn't seem to work—there's no noticeable change in the x position of the images as I scroll.
Parent Component: HorizontalScrollCarousel
This is my main horizontal scrolling component. It uses useScroll to track scrollYProgress and applies a transform to scroll the entire carousel horizontally.
import { motion, useTransform, useScroll } from "framer-motion";
import { useRef } from "react";
import ParallaxHoriz from '../../animations/ParallaxHoriz/ParallaxHoriz';
import "./HorizontalScrolling.css";

const HorizontalScrollCarousel = () => {
  const targetRef = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: targetRef,
  });

  const x = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["0%", "-100%"]);

  return (
    <section ref={targetRef} className="horizontal-scroll-carousel">
      <div className="carousel-container">
        <motion.div style={{ x }} className="carousel-content">
          <div className="carousel-card-container">
            {cards.map((card) => (
              <div key={card.id} className="card">
                <div className="card-image-container">
                  <ParallaxHoriz>
                    <div
                      className="card-image"
                      style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url(${card.url})`,
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "100%",
                      }}
                    ></div>
                  </ParallaxHoriz>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </motion.div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default HorizontalScrollCarousel;

const cards = [
  { url: "image1.jpg", id: 1 },
  { url: "image2.jpg", id: 2 },
  // Additional cards...
];


Parallax Component: ParallaxHoriz
This component wraps each image and uses useScroll and useTransform to create a parallax effect.
import React from 'react';
import { motion, useScroll, useTransform } from 'framer-motion';

const ParallaxHoriz = ({ children }) => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: ref,
    offset: ["start end", "end start"],
  });

  const x = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["-20%", "20%"]);

  return (
    <div ref={ref} style={{ overflow: "hidden", width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      <motion.div
        style={{
          width: "120%",
          height: "100%",
          x,
          position: "absolute",
          left: "-10%",
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParallaxHoriz;

.horizontal-scroll-carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000vh;
  background-color: #fdf7f0;
}

.carousel-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-content {
  display: flex;
  will-change: transform;
}

.carousel-card-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.card-image {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


The scrollYProgress value in ParallaxHoriz doesn't seem to update correctly, or the useTransform is not applying as expected.
Logging scrollYProgress shows it remains constant (or barely changes), even as I scroll.
The horizontal scrolling of the parent carousel (x in HorizontalScrollCarousel) works, but the parallax effect on individual images does not.
